# How to overlap a ExpansionTile widget over other widget when clicked?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

[image: My flutter web project]

I have a GridList of ExpansionTile widgets and each of them are wrapped over a Card Widget.

My problem is when I click on any ExpansionTile widget I get pixel overflow error.
How to solve this?

```
//This is my main page
return Container(
  width: queryData.size.width*0.65,
  child: GridView.count(
    primary: false,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    childAspectRatio: 3.5,
    children: <Widget>[
      Card(child: ShadyExpansionTile()),
      Card(child: ShadyExpansionTile()),
      Card(child: ShadyExpansionTile()),
      Card(child: ShadyExpansionTile()),
    ],
  ),
);

  //This is my custom ExpansionTile(Shady is my nick name)
    class ShadyExpansionTile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
        title: Text('my title'),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. '),
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using gridview? Can you try wrap instead? Try adding SingleShildScrollViewer or creating a stack.